# Alter default audio output device from command-line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, audio, script

I have 2 audio output devices:

1. 5.1 Speaker System attached via Toslink
2. Gaming Headset attached via USB

Is there a simple way to change which device is the default output device, from the command-line?  I'm interested in scripting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps take a look at the [AudioSwitch](https://code.google.com/p/audioswitch/) project, it has also command-line options.

Examples:

1. `AudioSwitch.exe -i 1` -- will change 1'th device as default and run AudioSwitch.
2. `AudioSwitch.exe -i 0 -x` -- will change 0'th device as default and exit.
3. `AudioSwitch.exe -l -i 0 -x` -- will show device list, set 0'th device as default and exit.

Comment: After using this for a while, AudioSwitch is perfect! I can highly recommend it. Very easy to use and nothing to miss.